# Why is this tooltip having two different start positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm trying to make a tooltip so when you hover a word a box appears beneath the word and you can also move your mouse down into the tooltip and the tooltip will stay visible.

Now my problem is that it needs to be responsive. I want the tooltip directly centered beneath the word, but if there is not enough space on the left, it will shift over to the right as much as it has to.

This I have accomplished, see code below. The problem though that I am having is that I want there to always be at least 20 pixels of padding on the left side, no matter what the screensize.

When I try to add a bit of math to do this, the box sometimes applies the the padding and other times it doesn't. Seems completely random. The best way to replicate this problem is to look at the jsfiddle I have provided and open console and toggle device toolbar on so you can resize to mobile. Now while this is active, click once on the text so the box shows up and then (because you are in mobile view) the box will stay visible until you click somewhere else. While it is visible, resize the browser fast and you will see what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/6nckuv1x/

```js
$("body").on("mouseenter", "[data-trigger-tooltip]", function() {
  ShowWarcraftCharacterTooltip($(this));
});

$("body").on("mouseleave", "[data-trigger-tooltip]", function () {
  $(this).find(".box").first().hide();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $("[data-trigger-tooltip]").each(function() {
    ShowWarcraftCharacterTooltip($(this));
  });
});

function ShowWarcraftCharacterTooltip(target) {
    var tooltip = target.find(".box").first();
    var leftPosition = target.offset().left;
    var tooltipWidth = tooltip.outerWidth() / 2;
    var tooltipLeftPosition = -(tooltipWidth);

    if (leftPosition < tooltipWidth) {
        tooltipLeftPosition = tooltipLeftPosition - (leftPosition - tooltipWidth);
    }

    if (tooltip.offset().left < 40) {
        tooltipLeftPosition += (40 - tooltip.offset().left);
    }

    var minWidth = $(window).width() - 70;

    if (minWidth > 320) {
        minWidth = 320;
    }

    tooltip.css({ left: tooltipLeftPosition, top: 10, minWidth: minWidth });
    tooltip.show();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="tooltip" data-trigger-tooltip>Test Word
    <div class="box"></div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a timeout to delay the resize function appears to fix the problem:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout($handleResize);
    $handleResize = setTimeout(function() {
        $("[data-trigger-tooltip]").each(function() {
            ShowWarcraftCharacterTooltip($(this));
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: No that doesn't seem to fix it when I try

Comment: if you open console, you will see the errors it throws, so the resize is not even called and thus it appears its fixed.